# warning message shows during the file upload using php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using ubuntu os with XAMPP. Here i've created two files uploader.php and phpEx6.php
when i try to upload a file it shows warning message.I am new to php.pls help to solve the problem..

phpEx6.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-   data">
<input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

uploader.php

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/' $_FILES['file']['name'])
or die("Couldn't copy the file.");

}
else
{
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>enter code here
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?> bytes
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/opt/lampp/htdocs/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/sam.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploader.php on line 5

Warning: 
move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/php1BAGC1' to '/opt/lampp/htdocs/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/sam.txt' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploader.php on line 5

Comment: Sounds like the upload failes due missing filesystem permissions. Does the webserver-daemon user has access to the upload dir? Besides: what's that `enctype="multipart/form-   data"`?!

Comment: Make sure the directory you're trying to move to really exists

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/' .$_FILES['file']['name']     maybe?

Comment: i just need to know to upload a file from one dir to another if any one having simple code for beginners to understand pls post it.....

Comment: Looking for file in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/sam.txt` instead of `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/sam.txt`. Look at your `move_uploaded_file()` method.

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  does not play well with this path '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/' try cutting this /opt/lampp/htdocs 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
    The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file. Which most likely in your case is opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 1):

try altering this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name'])
```

with this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/xampp/nf/uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name'])
```

or even this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name'])
```

Comment: sorry there was a missing dot between path '/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads/' and $_FILES['file']['name'], haven't seen it in your code above. I corrected it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about, there's no folder created to which you are trying to move the files.. Create the folder and then try it or check whether the folder has all the permissions needed to upload the file into it..
Here's the sample code for Uploading a file..

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['Pic']['tmp_name'];
        $name = $_FILES['Pic']['name']; 

        if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
        {
            $org_name = time()."_".$name;
            $dest = "uploads/$org_name";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have **uploads** folder _"/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/nf/uploads"_

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the folder.. Generally in Linux it won't have all the permissions...

Answer (score 0):

there can be multiple answer for your questions as followed:

1. start path with DOT(.) such as './opt/foldername/'
2. create folder and give write permission to it in which you want to insert your file and data
3. or you can do before move uploaded in such as way just check first whether directory exist or not if its not than use mkdir function and than chmod to give write permission and than use upload function. its always a better practice to check directory existence and than only move the file there.

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/xampp/nf/uploads/'. $_FILES['file']['name'])
```

@Peter Darmis